# How to differentiate legitmate URL redirects from ISP redirects or other hijacks

Tags: vba, url, redirect

I'm trying to use VBA to test URLs for bad links and redirects.

I'm able to obtain redirect URLs using HTTP request GET method for URLs that return a 3xx series .Status response using either MSXML2 or WinHttp libraries through VBA.

When I attempt this method for some URLs that have legitimate (intended by the URL site) redirects, I receive an error when trying to obtain the Request object.

For example, when this URL is entered into a browser:
http://www.teconnectivity.com
...the browser will ultimately arrive at this address:
http://www.te.com/en/home.html

However this VBA code will return  Error -2147012744: "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response". The error is thrown on the .Send statement.

```
Sub Test()
   Debug.Print sGetRedirectURL("http://www.teconnectivity.com/")                            
End Sub

Private Function sGetRedirectURL(ByVal sURL As String) As String
 Dim oRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
 Dim sReturn As String

 Set oRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

 On Error GoTo ErrProc
 With oRequest
   .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False
   .Open "GET", sURL, False
   .Send
   If Left$(.Status, 1) = "3" Then
      sReturn = .GetResponseHeader("Location")
   End If
 End With
 On Error GoTo 0

ExitProc:
 sGetRedirectURL = sReturn
 Exit Function

ErrProc:
 Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
 Resume ExitProc
End Function
```

How is my browser able to get to the destination: http://www.te.com/en/home.html, if an HTTP request with that URL returns an error?

I can use the browser's application to get the final destination URL like this:

```
Function sGetFinalURL(sURL As String) As String
 Dim oAppIE As Object
 Dim sReturn As String

 Set oAppIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 With oAppIE
   .Navigate sURL

   Do While .Busy
   Loop
   sReturn = .document.url
   .Quit
 End With
 Set oAppIE = Nothing

 sGetFinalURL = sReturn
End Function
```

However, that approach will also return URLs for ISP redirects or other hijacks.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I ended up taking for this was to use the browser application to try to navigate to a non-existent domain URL. If the browser arrives at a URL, then that means it has been redirected by the ISP or something other than the non-existent domain.

```
Private Function sGetNXDomainRedirect() As String
'--attempts to return the domain used to redirect non-existant
'    domain urls. Used to distinguish legitimate redirects
'    from ISP redirects or other hijacks
'--returns "NoRedirect" if the bogus url is not redirected.

 Dim sReturn As String
 Dim oIEapp As Object
 Dim uTest As udtHttpInfo

 Const sBOGUS_URL As String = _
   "http://wwXYXw.NXDomainToTest"

 Set oIEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 With oIEapp
   .Navigate sBOGUS_URL

   Do While .Busy
   Loop

   On Error Resume Next
   sReturn = .document.Domain
   On Error GoTo 0
   .Quit
 End With

 Set oIEapp = Nothing

 If Len(sReturn) = 0 Then sReturn = "NoRedirect"
 sGetNXDomainRedirect = sReturn
End Function
```

[Link to complete code on MrExcel.com forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/849481-find-broken-links-excel-2013-a.html#post4143886)

Once that "ISP Redirect" site is known, then the IE Application can be used to test for bad links or legitimate redirects. If the Navigation through the IE Application returns a domain other than the ISP Redirect domain, then I interpret that as a legitimate redirect.

Comment: Since it's been 7 days without an answer or comment, I thought I'd share the best approach I came up with. It's not as robust as I was hoping to find. I'm still interested if anyone can suggest something better.